# My macbook pro 2013 won’t charge or turn on

Tags: macbook-pro, charging

Recently and out of the blue my macbook pro 2013 retina display (model no: A1502) stopped turning on or charging.

- Charge light green then orange
- Tried different known working chargers/outlets
- Repair shop in Colombia tried with own cable/charger, also did not charge
- This was US voltage 110V, change to 220V did not change things for the better
- Battery looks fine physically, no visible damage inside the machine
- SMC reset led to the charge light turning green and then orange
  again, so there seems to be some life left in the machine
- No other signs of life besides that
- No previous problems, machine held a good charge (3-4 hours)
- MacOS relatively current: 10.15 Catalina

The machine, while old, has a high emotional value to me , so please help!!!

Looking forward to any ideas or suggestions, thanks a lot in advance

Comment: It needs a new battery. It's 10 years old!

Comment: Battery was fine before it died, decline was slow and as mentioned it held a good charge before it died. the guys in columbia also said it was ok and "asking for electricity".

Comment: It's not always linear decline. Sometimes it works fine until it just stops. Batteries have a lifespan.